# laravel eloquent relation with 3 table

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I want query from 3 table

user:

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Denny     |
|  2 | Agus      |
|  3 | Dini      |
|  4 | Angel     |
+----+-----------+
```

History_Education

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id |   userId  | educationId |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |  1        | 1           |
|  2 |  1        | 2           |
|  3 |  2        | 1           |
|  4 |  2        | 2           |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

Education

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id |   level   |   Name   |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 1         |   SD     |
|  2 | 2         |   SMP    |
|  3 | 3         |   SMA    |
|  4 | 4         |   S1     |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

How to query with laravel Eloquent to get the latest user education order by Level DESC
expected:

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+
| id |   Name    |   Latest_Education   |
+----+-----------+----------------------+
|  1 | Denny     |   SMP                |
|  2 | Agus      |   SMP                |
|  3 | Dini      |    -                 |
|  4 | Angel     |    -                 |
+----+-----------+----------------------+
```

In normal query: 
select id,name ,(select E.name from education E inner join History_eductaion HE on E.id = HE.education_id where HE.userId =U.id  limit 1 order by E.level DESC )latest_education from USER U

How to translate to laravel eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is use the query builder - your query needed to be altered slightly to match the table names and columns as listed in your question:

```
$result = DB::table('user')
    ->select([
        'id',
        'name',
        DB::raw("(select E.name from Education E inner join History_Education HE on E.id = HE.educationId where HE.userId = user.id order by E.level DESC limit 1) as latest_education")
    ])
    ->get();
```